# In safari browser, when i redirecting from window.open the first load is fine with HTTPS and second time it says not secure

Tags: javascript, safari

```js
function openInstaplayWindow() {

      var new_window_height = window.innerHeight;
      var new_window_position = (window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio) / 2;
      new_window_position = new_window_position - 195;
      var params = `width=390,height=`+ new_window_height + `,left=` + new_window_position + `,top=0,resizable=no`;
      var newWindow = window.open("https://www.pokertempo.com/instaplay-desktop", "_blank", params);
}
```

Comment: What you mean by `second time`? How you use this function?

Comment: I just simply call it by onclick method from button...First time new window open as https but on second time it open as not secure.. Then after clear cache it repeated same. Please check on this url on safari https://www.pokertempo.com after load click on play button. The new window will appear first time as https and after close then open again from play button then new window open as not secure. I don't know what's exactly issue it is.